# Create Azure Load Balancer with Standard SKU using Fluent azure API

Tags: azure, azure-management-api

Using [Azure Fluent API](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net) I need to create Load Balancer with Standard SKU. The option I get are

```
azure.LoadBalancers.Define("").WithRegion(Region.USWest).WithNewResourceGroup().DefineInboundNatPool()
```

There is no option to mentions SKU Basic or Standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no option to mentions SKU Basic or Standard.

We could do that with `.WithSku(LoadBalancerSkuType.Basic) or .WithSku(LoadBalancerSkuType.Standard)`. For more information, you could refer the following demo code

```
var loadBlance =  azure.LoadBalancers
                  .Define("loadbalancer Name")
                  .WithRegion("region Name")
                  .WithExistingResourceGroup("Resource Group")
                  .DefineInboundNatPool("NatPoolName")
                  .WithProtocol(new TransportProtocol())    
                  .FromFrontend("frontendName")
                  .FromFrontendPortRange(intFrom,intTo)
                  .ToBackendPort(port)
                  .Attach()
                  .WithSku(LoadBalancerSkuType.Basic) //define SKU
                  .Create();
```